# Is there a way to construct a MonetaryAmount from a whole cents value?

Tags: java, java-money, jsr354

Given a price-point represented as an integer of whole cents, i.e. `199 = $1.99`, is there an API method for constructing a `MonetaryAmount`?

One simple method would be to divide the amount by 100, but wondering if there's an API method for this.

```
MonetaryAmount ma = Money.of(199, "NZD").divide(100);
```

Comment: All I could find is [Money.of(199, "NZD").scaleByPowerOfTen(-2)](http://mavenbrowse.pauldoo.com/central/javax/money/money-api/0.8/money-api-0.8-javadoc.jar/-/javax/money/MonetaryAmount.html#scaleByPowerOfTen(int)) ...

Comment: I thought about that also but was concerned about the scale being changed with it. From what I'd imagine the original dollar value would ultimately be the same since the scale changes with the value. Haven't tested the theory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Money.ofMinor()](https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-ri/blob/master/src/main/java/org/javamoney/moneta/Money.java#L819) method is exactly what you are looking for.

> Obtains an instance of `Money` from an amount in minor units.
>   For example, `ofMinor(USD, 1234, 2)` creates the instance `USD 12.34`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is useful to you. It works, though.

```
private void convert() {
    DecimalFormat dOffset = new DecimalFormat();
    DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");        
    dOffset.setMultiplier(100);


    String value2, value1;

    String str;
    try {
        value1 = "0";
        value2 = dFormat.format(dOffset.parse(value1));
        System.out.println(value2);

        value1 = "7";
        value2 = dFormat.format(dOffset.parse(value1));
        System.out.println(value2);

        value1 = "04";
        value2 = dFormat.format(dOffset.parse(value1));
        System.out.println(value2);

        value1 = "123";
        value2 = dFormat.format(dOffset.parse(value1));
        System.out.println(value2);

        value1 = "123456";
        value2 = dFormat.format(dOffset.parse(value1));
        System.out.println(value2);


    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }        
}

/* Output
    0.00
    0.07
    0.04
    1.23
    1,234.56   
*/
```

Comment: I'm after a [jsr-354](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=354) specific answer for creating instances of `MonetaryAmount`. What I'd like to see is something like `Money.of(199, "NZC")`.

Comment: Money.ofMinor(NZC, 199) is what you are looking for